# Как сделать, что-бы 3 символа попадались не более 1 раза?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Цель: после `text/` идут:

1. любые символы из диапазона `[а-яё]`
2. не первым и не последним символом, а так же максимум 1 раз могут встречаться: **пробел**, **дефис**, **апостроф**.

Входной текст:

1. Должно быть выделено:

   ```
   text/выаваываыва  
   text/выава ываыва  
   text/выава'ываыва  
   text/выава-ываыва  
   text/выава'ываыва ываыва  
   text/выава-ываыва'ываыва  
   text/выава ываыва-выава'ываыва  
   text/выава-ываыва'выава ываыва  
   text/выава'ываыва выава-ываыва
   ```
2. Не должно быть выделено:

   ```
   text/выава ываыва ываыва  
   text/выава'ываыва'ываыва  
   text/выава ываыва выава'ываыва  
   text/выава-ываыва-выава ываыва  
   text/выава'ываыва'выава-ываыва  
   text/1выаваываыва  
   text/выаваываыва2
   ```

P.S. пробелы в конце строк убрать, пришлось проставить, а то этот форум не хочет переносить без них...
Попытки были, `^text\/(?:[а-яё])+(\s?-?'?)*[а-яё]+$` работает, если пробел ИЛИ кавычка ИЛИ тире встречается 1 раз. А нужно до 1 раза для каждого.

Answer (score 1):

[сам решил](https://regex101.com/r/9VUJWP/13), громоздко, но по-другому не придумал.

```
/#Внимание на модификаторы
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<g>[а-яё]+)
  (?<g1>[а-яё]+\s)
  (?<g2>[а-яё]+')
  (?<g3>[а-яё]+-)
  (?<allIncludes>(
    \g<g1>\g<g2>\g<g3>|
    \g<g1>\g<g3>\g<g2>|
    \g<g2>\g<g1>\g<g3>|
    \g<g2>\g<g3>\g<g1>|
    \g<g3>\g<g1>\g<g2>|
    \g<g3>\g<g2>\g<g1>
    )\g<g>$
  )
  (?<twoIncludes>(
    \g<g1>\g<g2>|\g<g1>\g<g3>|
    \g<g2>\g<g1>|\g<g2>\g<g3>|
    \g<g3>\g<g1>|\g<g3>\g<g2>
    )\g<g>$
  )
  (?<result>\g<allIncludes>|\g<twoIncludes>|
    (\g<g1>|\g<g2>|\g<g3>)?\g<g>$)
)
^text\/\g<result>/gmix
```